# How to make sed get first occurance rather than the last?

Tags: sed

My string :

```
<p> <strong>Linux x86_64/AMD64/EM64T</strong><br> Latest Long Lived Branch Version: <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/163238/en-us">450.66</a><br> Latest Short Lived Branch Version: <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/150803/en-us">435.21</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU version (390.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/160182/en-us">390.138</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU version (340.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156163/en-us">340.108</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU version (304.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/123709/en-us">304.137</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU Version (71.86.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-71.86.15-driver.html">71.86.15</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU Version (96.43.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-96.43.23-driver.html">96.43.23</a><br> Latest Legacy GPU Version (173.14.xx series): <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71303/en-us">173.14.39</a><br> <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-amd64-display-archive.html">Archive</a></p>
```

Piping that string to `sed 's|^.*">\([0-9\.]*\)<.*$|\1|'` produces `173.14.39` which is the last version number. But I want `450.66` which is the first version number. How to edit the above `sed` argument to achieve that?

I am still a beginner at `sed`, so please be verbose.

Comment: the `s` switch of `sed` is for substitution. if you want to extract the version numbers no need for substitution.

Comment: The `*` quantifier is _greedy_, i.e., it will match as many characters as possible. What you want here is to use a lazy (reluctant) quantifier instead. Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't directly support that. You could use another tool, such as `perl` or `awk`. If you want to use `sed`, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed for a discussion on how to simulate non-greedy quantifiers with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.*` is greedy, it will match as much as possible before the rest of the expression matches anything.  This is why you get the last match rather than the first.

A workaround is to do two substitutions.  One that removes all HTML markup after the wanted number, and then another that deletes the markup at the start of the remaining string:

```
$ sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)<.*/\1/' -e 's/.*>//' file
450.66
```

The first expression, `s/\([[:digit:]]\)<.*/\1/`, replaces the end of the string with the first digit found immediately preceding a `<` character. We're guaranteed that the string will be truncated at the *first* match of `[[:digit:]]<` since we use `.*` *after* that pattern.

This expression leaves us with

```
<p> <strong>Linux x86_64/AMD64/EM64T</strong><br> Latest Long Lived Branch Version: <a href="https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/163238/en-us">450.66
```

The second expression, `s/.*>//`, simply chops off everything from the start of the string up until that last `>` character.  Here, we're *relying* on `.*` to match as much as possible at the *start* of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` instead like this:

```
awk -F 'en-us">|</a>' '{print $2}'
```

The `-F` option is telling `awk` to use either `en-us">` or `</a>` as a field separator instead of the default to split the line up.

And then it is just a matter of printing the correct field. In this case, it is the second field with `print $2`.

This is all assuming your sample string is not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fight greed. This can be done in 2 steps. The first is to delete everything that comes after the first match and the second is to delete everything that comes before the match

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9][^<]*).*/\1/; s/.*>(.*)$/\1/' file
```

The next way is universal. It allows you to make a selection of any template in the string

```
sed -r 's/(>[0-9]+\.[0-9][^<]*)/\1\r/8; s/.*>(.*)\r.*/\1/' file
173.14.39
```

We put a flag `\r` at the end of the templates according to the specified number in the substitution command, then we make a selection based on the flag. The examples use templates 1 and 2. Experiment with numbers

```
sed -r 's/(>[0-9]+\.[0-9][^<]*)/\1\r/2; s/.*>(.*)\r.*/\1/' file
435.21
sed -r 's/(>[0-9]+\.[0-9][^<]*)/\1\r/1; s/.*>(.*)\r.*/\1/' file
450.66
```

Answer (score 0):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

The code below is a good jumping-off point when starting to use Raku. Once you get your regex correct, you can change the code slightly to get the exact output you want:

```
~$ raku -ne 'm:g/ (\d+ \. \d+) /.put ;'
```

OR

```
~$ raku -ne 'm:g/ (<digit>+ \. <digit>+) /.put ;'
```

OR

```
~$ raku -ne 'm:g/ (<digit>+ \. <digit>+) /; put $/ ;'
```

Output (in all 3 cases):

```
450.66 435.21 390.138 340.108 304.137 71.86 71.86 71.86 96.43 96.43 96.43 173.14 173.14
```

Above you're basically asking Raku to examine your input line-by-line ( `-ne` Flag), find all match instances, i.e. "match:global" (`m:g`) against the `(<digit>+ \. <digit>+)` regular expression. Parentheses around the `(<digit>+ \. <digit>+)` indicates the extent of your capture (i.e. the whole match). Each match on the input line gets saved as `$0` , `$1` , `$2`, etc. in the match variable `$/` .

So that's it. Since you want the first match, all you have to do is pull out `$0` , and I find it easiest to write that code like so:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put $0 if m:g/ (<digit>+ \. <digit>+) /;'
```

OR this:

```
~$ raku -ne 'm:g/ (<digit>+ \. <digit>+) /; put $0;'
```

Output (in both cases):

```
450.66
```

HTH.

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

awk command

```
awk -F "en-us" '{gsub(/<.*/,"",$2);print $2 }' l| awk '{gsub(/^">/,"",$0);print }'
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
o=re.compile(r'<.*')
k=open('l','r')
for i in  k:
    j=i.split("en-us")[1]
    print re.sub(o,"",j).replace('">','')
```

output

```
450.66
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk instead of sed for that, e.g. with GNU awk for multi-char RS to print the 1st version number:

```
$ awk -v RS='</a>' -F'>' '{print $NF; exit}' file
450.66
```

to print the 3rd:

```
$ awk -v RS='</a>' -F'>' 'NR==3{print $NF; exit}' file
390.138
```

or the 6th:

```
$ awk -v RS='</a>' -F'>' 'NR==6{print $NF; exit}' file
71.86.15
```

or the one associated with 304.xx series:

```
$ awk -v RS='</a>' -F'>' '/304.xx series/{print $NF; exit}' file
304.137
```

and so on.